# Connecting to mac_server with IDA Pro on Windows

Tags: ida, osx

I can't get IDA to connect with a debugging server on OS X. This is what keeps happening:

```
$ ll ~/.bin/mac_server*
-rwxr-sr-x  1 Ron  procmod   657K May  5 22:29 mac_server*
-rwxr-sr-x  1 Ron  procmod   666K May  5 22:29 mac_serverx64*
$ mac_serverx64
IDA Mac OS X 64-bit remote debug server(MT) v1.17. Hex-Rays (c) 2004-2014
Listening on port #23946...
=========================================================
[1] Accepting connection from 172.16.91.129...
Current group=procmod
Current group=procmod
Current group=procmod
Current group=procmod
Current group=procmod
Current group=procmod
Current group=procmod
Current group=procmod
Current group=procmod
Current group=procmod
[1] Closing connection from 172.16.91.129...
```

I'm running IDA Pro 6.6 on Windows and `mac_server` on OS X Yosemite 10.3. Did I miss something crucial?

Comment: What are the errors you get from Ida Pro?